# Update information is outdated

Tags: apt, update-manager, updates

How can I fix my update problem. I am using Maverick 10.10 and update daily, however I get the warning triangle that tells me that the update information is outdated. After I perform an update it tells me that it was last updated 26 days ago.

Upon looking at the sources list in `/etc/apt/sources.list` it shows the following:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.10 _Maverick Meerkat_ - Release i386 (20101007)]/ maverick main restricted
# See http:/ /help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http:// mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick universe
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick multiverse
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main

deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-security universe
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-security universe
deb http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirror01.th.ifl.net/ubuntu/ maverick-security multiverse
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/awn-testing/ubuntu hardy main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/awn-testing/ubuntu hardy main
#E-UAE and other funky Amiga stuff
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bjfs/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

Comment: Is there any warnings when you do an update? What does `sudo apt-get update` say?

Comment: Update your main post with the things you tried (eg the methods suggested here) and their errors messages so people don't have to dig through every comment to find that info.

Comment: Can you please reformat that using the code formatting? It's just unreadable as it is now.

Comment: You'll see this when one or more of your sources fails to update.  You can manually comment out or remove those, but I'm not sure this is the best way to preserve your desired sources.  Ah -- looks like you need to get the correct gpg key.  I'll update if someone doesn't do it first.

Comment: reformatting - do i just put 4 spaces before each line?

Answer (score 3):

You'll see this kind of message when one or more of your sources fails to update. 
Sometimes this is because your system can't get to one of the sites to download repository information (this is usually because of an outage at the site in question, a problem with an internet link somewhere along the path to the site, or a problem with DNS).
Here it looks like you can't confirm the identity of the site, so Ubuntu doesn't think it is safe to use this source.

Based on your update output, you'll need to get the correct identity key for tuxfamily.org, or comment it out of your sources.

See these answers for explicit help:  [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey-without-terminal)

Comment: do i really need the public key for hardy and jaunty release

Comment: @Meddy  Ah.  You should probably just comment those out in your /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: @Meddy Any luck?

Comment: Can we just wait it out or we have to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

run

```
  sudo aptitude
```

press u

then g

accept the changes if any (which means some dependencies have to be resolved)

and g again if necessary

Comment: command not found

Comment: sudo apt-get install aptitude

Answer (score 0):

You should simply run: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: tried that it doesnt sort the problem

Comment: tried sudo apt-get update and it scrolls through loads of mirrors then gives me:: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net hardy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7D2C7A23BF810CD5

Comment: sorry. Please also run `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net jaunty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0CC1223EE2314809

Comment: : GPG error: http://morgoth.free.fr dapper-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8CC68B397E2E4741
W: Failed to fetch http://download.tuxfamily.org/syzygy42/dists/feisty/avant-window-navigator/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://download.tuxfamily.org/syzygy42/dists/feisty/avant-window-navigator/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: i ran upgrade as well and that didnt sort the problem

Comment: Why are you using dapper-backports if you're running maverick? Please remove the feisty and dapper-related repos from /etc/apt/sources.list (or update them, at least), and try again - they are outdated

Comment: i dont know why, i'm a noob to ubuntu and it came with the install

Comment: whats best to update them or remove them?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it came with the install. Unless you've gradually updated your Ubuntu installation over the years - in which case it would make sense that the repositories you added manually are still there. Nevertheless, they need to be updated to reflect the version you are using, or removed.

Comment: Depends. If you need software that's on those repos and not in the official one, then upgrade. If you don't, you might as well remove them.

Comment: ive just checked /etc/apt/sources.list and there is only deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu maverick main #Ubuntu Tweak Stable Source in there.

Comment: i only installed ubuntu 26 days ago. how do i update these repos

Comment: That is odd. You need to edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the files in the `/etc/apt/souces.list.d/` directory. You need administrator rights to do so, so don't forget to use `sudo`

Comment: Ok i need to edit but put what in there?

Comment: Please copy the content of the files in your question and I'll point you to what needs to be changed

Comment: ok you mean copy and paste into the sources list?

Comment: Just paste the content of the sources list in your initial question

Comment: sorry, paste it here or in the sources list

Comment: you mean the W:GPG errors?

Comment: No, the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: gotya! Hey like a muppet i was looking in the source.list.d folder instead of the sources list. I removed dapper and fiesty. I'll put the rest in the question. should i remove hardy and jaunty as well?

Comment: done! i've put spaces in the http's as it wont let me post otherwise