# Update manager always says it is outdated

Tags: 11.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update information is outdated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23390/update-information-is-outdated)

Though it installs updates, it always says the update information is some days old and the number of days is increasing daily. I think it keeps on installing some updates repeatedly like Google Chrome beta (approx. 31 MB).

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/23390/18612) and see if any of its answers help you?

Answer (score 3):

Update manager shows the time since last successful updates check from **all** of update repositories. So if it continually fails to access **at least one** updates source it will still show the time since all were successfully accessed.
I would recommend you to run an update in a terminal (`sudo apt-get update`) and see which repository is not accessible. You can then disable it or fix it and run update manager again.

Comment: the OP has mentioned **Google Chrome beta** and there is (or was) a problem regarding it described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/105102/does-someone-know-why-the-chromium-daily-package-isnt-build-anymore). So, as you suggest, disabling the relevant repository should help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on whatever applications you have installed the Ubuntu OS will have multiple updates daily on various packages, including the OS itself.  This is a very common occurrence and should not be worried about.  However... If you want you, can open **Update Manager** and under `Settings` you can set how often to `Check for Available Updates`.  I have mine set on every 2 days but you can set it for weekly, bi-weekly, or never.

**Note:** *If you select the never option updates will not be checked unless you click on the Check for Updates button.*